# Column 'a.p_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sum, max

```
select max(a.totalgoal)as 'MAXIMUM goles',p_id
from 
(select playerperform.p_id, SUM (playerperform.score)as totalgoal from playerperform  
Group by p_id)as a
```

Comment: i want to select p_id also .. but this query gives an error

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use the `RANK()` function for this:

```
SELECT *
from (select playerperform.p_id, SUM (playerperform.score)as totalgoal, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(playerperform.score)DESC) Rnk
      from playerperform  
      Group by p_id
      )as a
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

Comment: i want to show maximum goal and the player id (the player who have max goal)

Comment: Depending on database one of the two above should do that.

Comment: how can i select best sorcerer this query gives all players ? and their marks ...... plz help

Comment: It doesn't return all, it returns 1.  What database are you using?

Comment: i have 2 highest scorer

Comment: TOP 1<< TOP 2 ? i can use but sir if there are 3 highest scorer this query will give only 2 players

Comment: Yeah if there's a tie you'll want to use a different approach, what database are you using?

Comment: [sql-server-2008-r2] ms sql

Comment: SELECT *
from (select playerperform.p_id,player.first_name, SUM (playerperform.score)as totalgoal, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(playerperform.score)DESC) Rnk
      from playerperform,player  
      Group by p_id
      )as a
WHERE Rnk = 1<<<<<<< sir i want to put player name also how can i put that? player name is in other table  call "Player"